# Magento new extension shows 404 page

Tags: php, magento

I have just started magento. I want to develop a simple magento extension showing helloworld. But when I want to access my extension page by `frontname` it always shows my `404 error`.

I have created a folder `Mycompany` in `app/local`. Then I created a folder `Tbc`. Then I created `etc` folder and created a `config.xml` file that looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Tbc>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompany_Tbc>
 </modules>
 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <tbc>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mycompany_Tbc</module>
                <frontName>tbc</frontName>
            </args>
        </tbc>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <tbc>
                <file>tbc.xml</file>
            </tbc>
        </updates>
    </layout>
 </frontend>
</config>
```

Then I created a `controllers` directory in my module directory and created an `IndexController.php` file in that directory like

```
class Mycompany_Tbc_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
/**
 * index action
 */
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'reached here';
        die();
    }
}
```

Then I created a `Mycompany_Tbc.xml` file in `app/etc/modules` which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Tbc>
        <active>true</active>
        <codepool>local</codepool>
    </Mycompany_Tbc>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I can see my module enabled in admin panel.
But now I want to access `magento.local/tbc` or `magento.local/index.php/tbc`, it always gives a `404` error. I have installed [this module](https://github.com/astorm/MagentoBetter404) for better 404 errors and due to this extension the 404 page shows

```
Page not Found
 We couldn't find a page at the URL you specified. The information below will help a Magento programmer figure out why.

Original Path
Original Path Information /tbc.

Module/Front Name
Module/Front Name: tbc.

No modules claim [tbc] as a <frontName/>`.
```

I have tried creating many extensions from scratch but getting same error and clearing cache many times. I am using `magento 1.9`

**NOTE** I am doing it at localhost and `magento.local` in my virtual host. I have created virtual host after installation of magento then change the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in `config_cache_data` table.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are silly mistake in  `Mycompany_Tbc.xml`

```
<codepool>local</codepool>
```

should be `<codePool>local</codePool>`

Comment: Dude you have saved my cell and head which I was going to hit on wall :p :p :p :p :p heads off to you dude

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompany_Tbc>

<!-- Whether our module is active: true or false -->

        <active>true</active>

<!-- Which codePool to use: core, community or local -->
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Mycompany_Tbc>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/core - Holds modules that are distributed with the base Magento and make up the core functionality.

app/code/community - Holds modules that are developed by third-parties

app/code/local - Holds custom modules you developed, including Mage code overrides.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit about why your answer is a possible solution to the question? That would be helpful to future users as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this that was difficult to solve because of a cache plugin, but I found that I had built a module in Windows that worked fine,  though it didn't work on Linux.

The reason was because Magento expected the folder to be in:

app/code/local/Mycompany/Tbc/controllers and my folder was named Controllers - case didn't matter on Windows. Took a long time to work out...